# Get data from database in blade

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel. is there any way to get data from database directly to the blade.php without using controller ?

I want to hide a menu 'my Form' when user is not filled any form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like below

```
@php
    $data = \App\Models\User::all();
@endphp
```

or just use like below

```
@foreach(\App\Models\User::all() as $user)

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You could embed PHP code into your view using `@php` directive.
(https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#php)